# MBProgressHUD add to application window

Tags: ios5, mbprogresshud

```
`UIWindow *tempKeyboardWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows]objectAtIndex:0];


MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:tempKeyboardWindow animated:YES];

hud.animationType = MBProgressHUDAnimationZoomOut;

hud.dimBackground = YES;

hud.labelText = showString;
```

`

i need to add hud to my application window ,so i used above code but not working.can any one help me?

Comment: show that MBProgressHUD on self.window.rootViewController.view

Answer (score 1):

First you need to alloc init it as shown below

```
self.progressHud = [[MBProgressHUD alloc]initWithView:self.navigationController.view];
```

Then set it's required properties as below

```
self.progressHud.labelText = @"Processing Image";
self.progressHud.dimBackground = YES;
self.progressHud.animationType = MBProgressHUDAnimationZoom;
self.progressHud.delegate = self;
```

Then for show it use below code

```
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:self.progressHud];
[self.progressHud show:NO];
```